# How to integrate CakePHP 3 application with Firebase

Tags: php, cakephp, firebase, cakephp-3.0, angularfire

Having read documentations and tutorials for hours, I ended up in more confusion after all. So, here I'm asking for your help/tips and I'd really appreciate any effort helps me take a step further. Sorry for any mistakes I might possibly make, I'm quite newbie on this topic, so to say.

I'm building a web application, actually a single web page, that will start running as soon as it receives a GET/POST request from an external source. So, the page will be updated asynchronously if any request is received, for which I thought of using AngularJS and AngularFire on the front-end later on. I know there are many other ways and probably much simpler too, but I'm quite curious about how to integrate my CakePHP application with Firebase platform. So, let's stick with **CakePHP + Firebase** solutions for now.

So far, using the SDK [Firebase PHP Client](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php) made much sense, however, I'm still confused about the files that needs to be manipulated. Since there are simply not many -I've found none so far- examples that use CakePHP3 Framework with Firebase, I'm stuck here and I'd really appreciate any help here. Firstly, this code is given in the link and I wonder how it works and what those vars and constants stand for.

```
const DEFAULT_URL = 'https://kidsplace.firebaseio.com/';
const DEFAULT_TOKEN = 'MqL0c8tKCtheLSYcygYNtGhU8Z2hULOFs9OKPdEp';
const DEFAULT_PATH = '/firebase/example';

$firebase = new \Firebase\FirebaseLib(DEFAULT_URL, DEFAULT_TOKEN);

// --- storing an array ---
$test = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "i_love" => "lamp",
    "id" => 42
);
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$firebase->set(DEFAULT_PATH . '/' . $dateTime->format('c'), $test);

// --- storing a string ---
$firebase->set(DEFAULT_PATH . '/name/contact001', "John Doe");

// --- reading the stored string ---
$name = $firebase->get(DEFAULT_PATH . '/name/contact001');
```

And here is the main question, assuming that I have a test function on one of the end points of my application, let say *www.example.com/visits/test*, how do I make sure that my application is integrated to Firebase platform and any request sent to that end point is being listened continuously?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I solved it, just so you know. It's needed to add a test end point to the controller file that you're using. You can find your token using Project Settings in your project file. A quick example is below.

```
public function test()
{
  $DEFAULT_URL = 'YOUR_URL';
  $DEFAULT_TOKEN = 'YOUR_TOKEN';
  $DEFAULT_PATH = '/';

  $firebase = new \Firebase\FirebaseLib($DEFAULT_URL, $DEFAULT_TOKEN);

  $lines = [
    "I had a problem once",
    "I used Java to solve it",
    "Now, I have ProblemFactory",
  ];

  foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $foo = $firebase->push($DEFAULT_PATH."code/",$line);
    echo "child_added";
    sleep(0.1);
    echo "<br> ";
  }
```

Then, in order to capture the lines added on the front-end, you may use a code similar to the code below. You can easily reach the version that fits your code from your firebase console by clicking Add "firebase to your web app" button or sth like this.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js">  </script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
    authDomain: "YOUR-DOMAIN",
    databaseURL: "YOUR_URL",
    storageBucket: "YOUR_BUCKET",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  var codeRef = firebase.database().ref('code/');
  codeRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
  console.log(data.val());
  });
</script>
```

I'm not done with the app yet, however, this insight may help you deal with similar issues.

Comment: Its a cool one but its php and not cakephp. I think it would be cool if we could use the cakephp's model class to push and retrieve data from a firebase db.